# How to set paginationRowsPerPageOptions['ALL','50',''100'] in React-data-table

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-data-grid, react-data-table-component

> Hi Everyone,
> I am using the React-Data-Table component for displaying the data. My react data table is working fine. But, I need to set the pagination option [All, 50,100,150]. In the React-data-table component provides the "paginationRowsPerPageOptions" property for set the value for pagination dropdown. I am set the paginationRowsPerPageOptions[50,100,150] in my project. It's working fine. When I select the 100 value from the pagination dropdown, 100 records will be displayed. But, My goal is initially, I need to add the "All" string in my pagination dropdown, While I select the "ALL" dropdown from pagination, All records need to display in my data table. How Can I do it? I attached the sample code in the code sandbox link.

I am using the React-Data-Table component.

React-Data-Table:

Link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-data-table-sandbox-ccyuu

> I already added the "paginationComponentOptions={{ selectAllRowsItem: true, selectAllRowsItemText: 'ALL' }}" in my DataTable component. But, It added in my dropdown as last value. I need to add 'ALL' value initial condition.

ScreenShot:

[image: React-Data-Table ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1):

You can add this prop to enable the all option.

```
const paginationComponentOptions = {
  selectAllRowsItem: true,
  selectAllRowsItemText: 'ALL',
};

   <DataTable
      ...
      paginationComponentOptions={paginationComponentOptions}
      ...
    />
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-data-table-forked-d6m05?file=/src/index.js

Comment: paginationRowsPerPageOption property is a number type right?. How can I pass the "ALL" string value in this property and I am using a functional component in my project.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a working example.

Comment: I already added the property and also 'ALL' option is displayed in my dropdown, But, It is displayed in the last value,  I need to load the ALL dropdown value as initial condition. for ex: Dropdown order ALL, 50,100,150..

Comment: From a UX persective why would you want to assume to display all? The table could contain large set of data, hence, the useage of pagination.

Answer (score 1):

> I added the "paginationPerPage" property in my data table and I assigned my data length in "paginationPerPage" Value. My issue has been resolved.
> I attached a screenshot below.

[image: Added paginationPerPage Property in ReactDataTable]

Now, I am able to see the ALL value as default in my dropdown.